# Overlay frame transparency and scrolling issue

Tags: html, css

I need a loader for some pages which are long to load.

```
<div id="loader">
    <div id="loaderContent" >
        <img src="/im/loader.gif" />
        <p>Traitement en cours...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#loader {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #808080;
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: wait;
}

#loaderContent {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -55%);
    text-align: center;
    color:darkgreen;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 30px 30px 20px 30px;
}
```

I activated and deactivate it with jQuery `$("#loader").show()` and `$("#loader").hide()`. But I have two issues: the opacity of the content div is not taken in account (it is transparent even with `opacity:1`) and if I display it on a long page, user is able to scroll the body content...

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opacity is inherited from the parent container and can't be overwritten.

> The value applies to the element as a whole, including its contents, even though the value is not inherited by child elements. [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

So prefer the alpha channel of the background color :

```
background-color: rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.5);
```

Then, for the scrolling, you have to set the `overflow` property of your `body` to `hidden`, the content will be clipped. Default value is `visible` wich allow scrolling. Remove the proberty when you hide your loading frame. I trick I saw once is to apply a custom class to the body:

```
body.loading {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can use this class to display/hide your loading frame too :

```
body.loading #loader {
    display: block;
}
```

The solutions of these two problems is demonstrated in this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function loaderShow() {
    $("body").addClass("loading");
  };

  function loaderHide() {
    $("body").removeClass("loading");
  };
  // Les clicks sur les éléments ayant la classe "loaderOnClick" affichent le loader
  $('.loaderOnClick').click(function() {
    loaderShow();
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  line-height: 25px;
}
#loader {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: wait;
}
#loaderContent {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -55%);
  text-align: center;
  color: darkgreen;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 30px 30px 20px 30px;
}
body.loading {
  overflow: hidden;
}
body.loading #loader {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <p>Tu ne quaesieris, scire nefas, quem mihi, quem tibi finem di dederint, Leuconoe, nec Babylonios temptaris numeros. ut melius, quidquid erit, pati. seu pluris hiemes seu tribuit Iuppiter ultimam, quae nunc oppositis debilitat pumicibus mare Tyrrhenum.
    Sapias, vina liques et spatio brevi spem longam reseces. dum loquimur, fugerit invida aetas: carpe diem, quam minimum credula postero.</p>
  <p>Tu ne quaesieris, scire nefas, quem mihi, quem tibi finem di dederint, Leuconoe, nec Babylonios temptaris numeros. ut melius, quidquid erit, pati. seu pluris hiemes seu tribuit Iuppiter ultimam, quae nunc oppositis debilitat pumicibus mare Tyrrhenum.
    Sapias, vina liques et spatio brevi spem longam reseces. dum loquimur, fugerit invida aetas: carpe diem, quam minimum credula postero.</p>
  <p>Tu ne quaesieris, scire nefas, quem mihi, quem tibi finem di dederint, Leuconoe, nec Babylonios temptaris numeros. ut melius, quidquid erit, pati. seu pluris hiemes seu tribuit Iuppiter ultimam, quae nunc oppositis debilitat pumicibus mare Tyrrhenum.
    Sapias, vina liques et spatio brevi spem longam reseces. dum loquimur, fugerit invida aetas: carpe diem, quam minimum credula postero.</p>
  <p>Tu ne quaesieris, scire nefas, quem mihi, quem tibi finem di dederint, Leuconoe, nec Babylonios temptaris numeros. ut melius, quidquid erit, pati. seu pluris hiemes seu tribuit Iuppiter ultimam, quae nunc oppositis debilitat pumicibus mare Tyrrhenum.
    Sapias, vina liques et spatio brevi spem longam reseces. dum loquimur, fugerit invida aetas: carpe diem, quam minimum credula postero.</p>
  <p>Tu ne quaesieris, scire nefas, quem mihi, quem tibi finem di dederint, Leuconoe, nec Babylonios temptaris numeros. ut melius, quidquid erit, pati. seu pluris hiemes seu tribuit Iuppiter ultimam, quae nunc oppositis debilitat pumicibus mare Tyrrhenum.
    Sapias, vina liques et spatio brevi spem longam reseces. dum loquimur, fugerit invida aetas: carpe diem, quam minimum credula postero.</p>
  <p>Tu ne quaesieris, scire nefas, quem mihi, quem tibi finem di dederint, Leuconoe, nec Babylonios temptaris numeros. ut melius, quidquid erit, pati. seu pluris hiemes seu tribuit Iuppiter ultimam, quae nunc oppositis debilitat pumicibus mare Tyrrhenum.
    Sapias, vina liques et spatio brevi spem longam reseces. dum loquimur, fugerit invida aetas: carpe diem, quam minimum credula postero.</p>
  <p>Tu ne quaesieris, scire nefas, quem mihi, quem tibi finem di dederint, Leuconoe, nec Babylonios temptaris numeros. ut melius, quidquid erit, pati. seu pluris hiemes seu tribuit Iuppiter ultimam, quae nunc oppositis debilitat pumicibus mare Tyrrhenum.
    Sapias, vina liques et spatio brevi spem longam reseces. dum loquimur, fugerit invida aetas: carpe diem, quam minimum credula postero.</p>
  <p>Tu ne quaesieris, scire nefas, quem mihi, quem tibi finem di dederint, Leuconoe, nec Babylonios temptaris numeros. ut melius, quidquid erit, pati. seu pluris hiemes seu tribuit Iuppiter ultimam, quae nunc oppositis debilitat pumicibus mare Tyrrhenum.
    Sapias, vina liques et spatio brevi spem longam reseces. dum loquimur, fugerit invida aetas: carpe diem, quam minimum credula postero.</p>


  <p class="loaderOnClick">Click me !</p>

  <div id="loader">
    <div id="loaderContent">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXs15.gif" />
      <p>Traitement en cours...</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: your answer is better

Comment: Nice example. I found your css applied once to body and yours `loaderShow()/loaderHide()` methods elegant. TY.

Answer (score 1):

use background color alpha instead of opacity

```
#loader {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: rgba(120,120,120,0.5);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: wait;
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer as you was the first (14s before me) to answer the opacity issue.

Answer (score 0):

a css cleanup should do the trick.

```
#loader {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #808080;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: wait;
  padding-top: 40%;
}

#loaderContent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  color: darkgreen;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#loaderContent > img {
  margin: 10% auto;
  display: block;
}

#loaderContent > p {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Now you can `show()` and `hide()` without issue. It it is still scrolling then make this the last element in your `BODY`, and set `width` and `height` to `100%` on the `body` element.

Comment: No, it don't solve the opacity issue nor the scrolling issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the opacity issue, replace

```
background-color: #808080;
opacity: 0.5;
```

with

`background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);`

For the scroll problem, when you make the loader visible with jQuery, add also a class on body, `.wrapper` and add in the css:

```
body.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The result: https://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/2g3jL54b/7/

Comment: Nothing more than previous answers. You just re-use other people answers.

Comment: @user987456321 When I posted this I clicked on "Run code snippet" and I didn't saw in the text the link "Click". I didn't check all the code and I resolved this on jsfiddle. It is ok the previous answer, I agree, I had good intention and I voted for the other answer when I realized my answer come a little late :).